# Слова с одним значением, но с разными ударениями

Tags: фонетика

Какие существуют слова с одинаковым значением, но ударения ставятся по-разному, например: щавель на А, щавель на Е?

Comment: Правильно - щавЕль. А вопрос-то в чем?!

Answer (score 3):

Не понимаю, в чём вопрос. Вариант ударения в этом слове всего один — щаве́ль. Разноместное ударение допустимо, например, в слове *"творог"*. Если спрашивается термин, коим именуется такое явление, то его называют по-разному: вариативность ударения, разноместное ударение и др.

Comment: А может, два разных вида растения? Пищевой, в салат, и кормовой...

Comment: Никогда не видел, чтобы *щАвель* был допустим. Посмотрите здесь: http://dic.academic.ru/searchall.php?SWord=%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C&stype=0&p=0 Я уверен, что ни в одном словаре не будет вариативности.

Answer (score 3):

> слова с одинаковым значением, но ударения ставятся по-разному

Если Вы проедете по славянским странам, то Вы сможете услышать множество слов с одинаковым значением и одинаковым (или почти одинаковым) написанием, но с самыми неожиданными ударениями. И даже в разных регионах одной и той же страны (России, Украины, бывшей Югославии...).

Например, *крапИва*, *кропивА* (укр.) и т. п. и мн. др.

И конкретно про **щавель.** Цитата из [Википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A9%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C):

> щаве́ль, в некоторых регионах России распространён другой вариант произношения — ща́вель

Итак, литературный вариант -- это *щаве́ль*, но кое-где в местных говорах произносят *ща́вель*.

Если интересно знать, то абсолютно такая же ситуация с этим словом и на Украине. Я полез в словари, подумал, что, возможно, *ща́вель* — это украинизм. Нет, литературное укр. — *щаве́ль.* Хотя в живой разговорной украинской речи говорят и так и так.

Comment: Щ**а**вель - да, так многие говорят.

Comment: Мы здесь, на форуме, больше обсуждаем литературные нормы, нежели разговорные. Есть масса распространенных ошибок (то, что не соответствует словарям) во многих русскоязычных регионах.

Answer (score 0):

> слова с одинаковым значением но ударения ставятся поразному.

Здесь не хватает запятой, и слово "по-разному" пишется через дефис. Цитируйте, пожалуйста, без ошибок.